# Error: Could not find or load main class - Java Result: 1

Tags: java, netbeans

I made all the changes that i found when i search this error to google or here but i still get this error

> "Error: Could not find or load main class
>
> Java Result: 1" .

Can anyone help?

The code i am trying to run is

```
package vasil;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import se.sics.jasper.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        StarterClass sc = new StarterClass();

        ChessFrame cf = new ChessFrame();
    }

}
```

I am trying to solve 8 queens problem with prolog-java

Comment: ok..don't be sorry! Can you help me know or you want all the classes?

Comment: i have 5 classes and one main class

Comment: How are you trying to run the class? From console or from Netbeans?